# HOW TO GET: Time Zone Setting of FTP Server?

Tags: php, ftp, utc, gmt

I'm using PHP's ftp_rawlist function to get a listing of files and their associated last-modified date/time. For my purposes, I need to know the time zone (or offset) of the the last-modified date/time. The dates/times alone are useless to me as I need to convert them to UTC.

Is there anyway to figure out what the FTP server's time zone setting is?

Comment: try via ftp_exec command to run it :)  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-exec.php

Comment: What command do I execute to get the time zone setting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way defined in the FTP standard to determine remote server's time zone.

If you have write permissions to the FTP server I guess you could upload the file and then calculate the difference between the file time reported by FTP and locally.

Comment: I believe Dreamweaver uses this method.

Comment: Damn... That's the approach I was going to try but I was hoping there would be a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: But this way you cannot get information on daylight saving time if you want to be super precise.

Answer (score 1):

Many (most?) FTP server's support a non-standard `SITE ZONE` command for retrieving the server's timezone:

> The `SITE ZONE` command requests the UTF offset for the time zone in which the server is located, allowing some FTP clients to adjust file timestamps to reflect different source/destination time zones

Though the exact format of the response differs between server implementations, so be prepared to test the response for multiple formats, or use the `SYST` command to identify the server and parse accordingly.

However, this is usually not necessary anymore, as modern servers support new commands like `MDTM` and `MLSx` which can retrieve remote file timestamps as UTC to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. My approach was to create a folder in the root called /time and then read it back and check the folders creation date. I could then establish the time difference between my ftp client and the server. Hope this helps.

BTW I am using https://github.com/ArxOne/FTP

```
// Establish a fallback
var servertime = DateTime.Now;
try
{
    // query for the existance of a time folder
    var timefolder = ftpClient.ListEntries("/").FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "time");
    // delete it if found
    if (timefolder != null)
    {
        ftpClient.Delete("/time");
    }
    // if not found create one
    ftpClient.Mkd("/time");
    timefolder = ftpClient.ListEntries("/").FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "time");
    if (timefolder == null)
    {
        Logger.Fatal("Time check failed");
        return;
    }
    // now grab the time of the folder.
    servertime = timefolder.Date;
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    Logger.Fatal(x,"Time check fatal error");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, FTP protocol doesn't provide localtime explicitly. When write access is available, you can upload new file and check modification time. With no write access, you can periodically read FTP dir and note modification time of each entry. When modification time changes, you'll know server's localtime for sure. ~30 minute check will suffice, automatic of course :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to define your timezone in the start of your PHP code.

Example:

```php
date_default_timezone_set("CET");
```

For me this solution worked as it automatically converted the time of the server from a different timezone to the desired one.

Comment: This answer misses the FTP context and assumes the HTTP server where PHP is executed.