# Can Delphi Indy Ftp idFTP.GET Preserve the File's Created and Modified Date?

Tags: delphi, download, ftp, indy, delphi-xe7

I would like to ask if Delphi Indy ftp idFTP.GET can preserve the file's created and modified date? If not, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdFTP.Get()` creates a new local file, so the OS is going to assign the current date/time to that file by default.  To assign the remote file's timestamp to the local file, you will have to retrieve the remote file's timestamp using either `TIdFTP.FileDate()`, `TIdFTP.List()`, or `TIdFTP.ExtListDir()`, and then apply the timestamp to the local file using platform-specific APIs, such as [`SetFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime) on Windows, [`utimensat()`/`futimens()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html) on Linux, etc.

Comment: While this is true (and so very obvious): [HOW TO GET: Time Zone Setting of FTP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340299/4299358)

Comment: @AmigoJack that post is old. There are commands now to determine an FTP server's local timezone, and `TIdFTP` queries that by default, see the `TIdFTP.TZInfo` property. Also, `TIdFTP.FileDate()` and modern directory listings are able to provide timestamps as UTC, so you don't always need the server's timezone anyway.